# disabling a js script (buttons.js) the entire layout changes. Why?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm taking a look to this website http://planetshine.net/demo/regolith-wp/ trying to understand how the horizontal layout is obtained.

I'm just trying to disable the javascript libraries one by one (I want to identify those essential fot the layout and those less important). And beginning to disable only the "buttons.js" library the layout already changes (for example, the vertical scroll bar appears). I would understand why this script "buttons.js" is so influential for the layout.

Comment: feel free to look up which wp plugin that library is from and then look up what it does. you have the powers of the internet search and view-source at your disposal, use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CSS styles may be added by javascript after a page is loaded. This often occurs in plugins: sliders, custom scrollbars etc. You need to inspect places, where this happens and find out, which classes or html elements disappear. Then you can recreate them manually and the whole page will work as expected.